# GXT TextField or TextArea not decode html entites

Tags: textfield, gxt

i use grid cell renderer... and form bindig...
grid cell renderer valus is good
form bindig value is bad (

i tested: ff9 and last chrome

this bug ? or browser error ? or something else ?

sorry i little speak english....  (i use gtranslate)

error picture => http://test.eggproject.hu/gxt/textfieldentitesbugg.PNG

about json(gxt model)
{"ID":1,"user_email":"xxxx@xxxx.com","display_name":"XXX YYYY","user_cegnev":"","user_jogosultsag":"administrator","user_kedvezmeny":0,"user_city":0,"user_irsz":-1,"user_district":3,"user_street":241,"user_hazszam":"2813","user_emelet":"10","user_ajto":"588","user_kapucsengo":"58","user_comment":"óüöú\u0151\u0171áí","first_name":"Harangozo","last_name":"Gabor","user_telephone":"06111111","user_street2":""}

user_comment error displaying just textarea or textfield why ?

Comment: json => {"ID":1,"user_email":"xxxx@xxxx.com","display_name":"XXX YYYY","user_cegnev":"","user_jogosultsag":"administrator","user_kedvezmeny":0,"user_city":0,"user_irsz":-1,"user_district":3,"user_street":241,"user_hazszam":"2813","user_emelet":"10","user_ajto":"588","user_kapucsengo":"58","user_comment":"&oacute;&uuml;&ouml;&uacute;\u0151\u0171&aacute;&iacute;","first_name":"Harangozo","last_name":"Gabor","user_telephone":"06111111","user_street2":""}

Comment: i tested ... just textarea... other test string óüöúőűáí &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;asdasd&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the components each section is using. A grid is essentially a  tag which means any HTML encoded data loaded into this table is rendered correctly. Conversely A TextBox is a  tag which only displays exactly what can be seen.

A solution is a custom field binding which processes the data in and out.

```
public class HTMLParserBinding extends FieldBinding {

    protected Field<?> field;`

    public HTMLParserBinding( Field<?> field, String property ) {
        super(field, property);
        this.field = field;
    }

    protected Object onConvertFieldValue( Object value ) { 
         if (value == null) {
             return null;
         }
         return Format.htmlDecode(value.toString());
    }

    protected Object onConvertModelValue( Object value ) {
        if( value == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return Format.htmlEncode(value.toString());
    }
}
```